# Unable to Get Certificate - Cannot Find the Path Because it Does Not Exist

Tags: powershell, certificate

I'm trying to access a certificate that I've got under Trusted Root Certification Authorities, however when doing so, I receive the following error:

```
Cannot find path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My\THUMBPRINT' because it does not exist.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? This is how I'm trying to access it:

```
Get-Item "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\THUMBPRINT"
```

Comment: [like this](https://shellgeek.com/powershell-find-certificate-by-thumbprint/)

Comment: You wanna look in `Cert:\LocalMachine\Root`